# Дискуссировать и дискутировать?

Tags: этимология, орфография, стилистика

Варианты *дискуссировать* и *дискутировать* фиксируются словарями как равноправные, однако чем вызваны их различия? Какова этимология этих слов? И все-таки есть какие-нибудь нюансы, о которых нужно знать, выбирая нужное написание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ДИСКУТИРОВАТЬ; ДИСКУССИРОВАТЬ,** [от лат. discutere ―  исследовать, обсуждать].

В "дискутировать" сохраняется согласная Т источника, "дискуссировать" ―  от дискуссия.

Обычно  используется глагол "дискутировать", "дискуссировать" чаще встречается в текстах 30-х годов.

Если сравнивать фонетику слов, то, **как мне кажется**,  "дискутировать" удобнее для произношения, так как в "дискуссировать" возможна вставка Р  (дискурсировать), искажающая смысл слова.

Такая неоправданная вставка звука встречается в языке,  и связана она с неправильно понятой словообразовательной структурой слова, с неверным сближением данного слова с другими словами, близкими по значению (например, грейпфрут ― грейпфрукт).